# Using enable_if with struct specialization

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if

I am attempting to define a template that will will specify a storage type given another type T.  I'd like to use enable_if to catch all the arithmetic types.  Below is my attempt at this which complains the template is redeclared with 2 parameters.  I tried adding a 2nd dummy parm to the primary template but get a different error. How can this be done?

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
template <typename T> struct storage_type; // want compile error if no match
// template <typename T, typename T2=void> struct storage_type; // no joy
template <> struct storage_type<const char *> { typedef std::string type; };
template <> struct storage_type<std::string> { typedef std::string type; };
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type* = nullptr> 
    struct storage_type { typedef double type; };

// Use the storage_type template to allocate storage
template<typename T>
class MyStorage {
  public:
  typename storage_type<T>::type storage;
};

MyStorage<std::string> s;  // uses std::string
MyStorage<const char *> s2; // uses std::string
MyStorage<float> f;  // uses 'double'
```

Comment: Do note that `long double` can be larger than `double`.  Also `long long` is a minimum of 64 bits but could be larger.

Comment: Fix the [obvious stuff](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c085b6a1f9b5a20) first?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I believe that's what he's asking, how to fix that error.

Comment: @JustinTime Woin't help much in the long term.

Comment: My actual usage is somewhat different so I simplified the problem to ask the question by throwing in a simple double type.  Have no worries, I'm not trying to stuff a larger type into a smaller allocation.  Thanks for the sharp eyes though as that could have been really important and might save someone else reading this.

Answer (score 21):

You can do this by adding a second parameter to the primary template, then specialising to match it; you were on the right track, but didn't do it correctly.

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
// template <typename T> struct storage_type;                // Don't use this one.
template <typename T, typename T2=void> struct storage_type; // Use this one instead.
template <> struct storage_type<const char *> { typedef std::string type; };
template <> struct storage_type<std::string> { typedef std::string type; };

// This is a partial specialisation, not a separate template.
template <typename T> 
struct storage_type<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type> {
    typedef double type;
};

// Use the storage_type template to allocate storage
template<typename T>
class MyStorage {
  public:
  typename storage_type<T>::type storage;
};

MyStorage<std::string> s;  // uses std::string
MyStorage<const char *> s2; // uses std::string
MyStorage<float> f;  // uses 'double'

// -----

struct S {};

//MyStorage<S> breaker; // Error if uncommented.
```

[And voila](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22ec22a454565d77).